# Is there a Chinese Full Text Search Engine in nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, full-text-search, nlp

I plan to add a Chinese full text search engine feature into my web application. However, I failed to find any existing solution for this. There are search engine solution in nodejs, but Chinese is not supported. So my question would be:

1. If there is existing solution in nodejs, that would be awesome. Meanwhile, I am open to know how to build such from scratch.
2. I'm also open to know if there is such solution in other programming language.

As a newbie in search engine, I would like to hear more suggestions in terms of its basic structure, key components and other resources.

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 2):

I did not really understand that what role would node.js play in a Full Text Search Engine. Well why don't you try Apache Solr? It has a good set of analyzers for Chinese Language. It is the most popular Full Text Search Engine out there and is used by some of top internet companies. For Chinese Tokenization/Analyzer etc. http://java.dzone.com/articles/indexing-chinese-solr seems to be a good resource.